# multidimensional fourier series for heat equation

Tags: fourier-analysis, heat-equation

In the additional notes (luckily not examinable) for my PDE modelling module I stumbled across the following statement and was wondering how it was derived

---

$$\partial_t\theta=\alpha\left(\partial^2_x+\partial^2_y+\partial^2_z\right)\theta\tag{1}$$
$$\theta=\theta(x,y,z,t),\,\,\,(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3\tag{2}$$
subject to:
$$\theta(0,y,z,t)=\theta(1,y,z,t)=\theta(x,0,z,t)=\theta(x,1,z,t)=\theta(x,y,0,t)=\theta(x,y,1,t)=0\tag{3}$$
$$\theta(x,y,z,0)=f(x,y,z)\tag{4}$$
then the solution is:
$$\theta=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{p=1}^\infty B_{n,m,p}e^{-\alpha(n^2+m^2+p^2)\pi^2t}\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)\sin(p\pi z)$$
$$B_{n,m,p}=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y,z)\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)\sin(p\pi z)\,\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z$$

It is clear to me that the initial conditions are just each of the faces being held at zero for $t\ne0$ and an initial temperature as any function of $f(x,y,z)$ and that the series can be split up apart from the dependent constants, so how is this expression for $B$ derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $t=0$ we have
$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_{n,m,p \in \mathbb{N}}B_{n,m,p}\sin(n\pi x) \sin (m \pi y) \sin (p \pi z)$$
The functions $$\phi_{n,m,p}(x,y,z)=\sin(n\pi x) \sin (m \pi y) \sin (p \pi z)$$
form [an orthogonal basis of functions in $C^2([0,1]^3)$ (which satisfy the boundary)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). We have
$$\|\phi_{n,m,p}\|^2=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}\phi_{n,m,p}(x,y,z)^2dxdydz=\frac{1}{2^3}$$

Therefore
$$B_{n,m,p}=\color{red}{2^3}\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}f(x,y,z)\sin(n\pi x) \sin (m \pi y) \sin (p \pi z)dxdydz$$
This because any function $f \in C^2([0,1]^3)$ (which satisfies the boundary) can be represented as
$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_{n,m,p \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{\langle f,\phi_{n,m,p} \rangle}{\|\phi_{n,m,p}\|^2} \phi_{n,m,p}$$
where $\langle f,\phi_{n,m,p} \rangle/\|\phi_{n,m,p}\|^2=B_{n,m,p}$.

Comment: Ahh I see, I have not covered much of this notation so will have to look into it but thank you!

Comment: @HenryLee I fixed some formalities